# python generator yield statement not yield

Tags: python, generator, send, yield

Here is code I am running:

```
def infinite_Third() -> Generator:
    num = 1
    while True:
        if num % 3 ==0:
            i = (yield num)
            if i is not None:
                num = i
        num += 1 

if __name__=='__main__':
    third_gen = infinite_Third()
    for i in third_gen:
        print(f"it is {i}")          
        if i>1000:
            break    
        third_gen.send(10*i+1)
```

I am expecting to see results as:

```
it is 3
it is 33
it is 333
it is 3333
```

However, what I really get is:

```
it is 3
it is 36
it is 366
it is 3666
```

I think this might be related to using `send` in the main code, but couldn't figure out why. Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to consider the return value of `third_gen.send`

Comment: "Send value" and "receive value" aren't separate operations in a generator. `send` also receives a value.

Answer (score 1):

Follow up from my comment, I've modified your main loop

- First, we send a `None` to start the generator and receive the first value
- After that, we send one value and receive the next one

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    third_gen = infinite_Third()
    i = third_gen.send(None)
    while True:
        print(f"it is {i}")
        i = third_gen.send(10*i+1)
        if i > 1000:
            break
```

Comment: it doesn't give the expected output.

Comment: It took me a while to understand what you meant, but I think it's just the first `i` value that was missing from the output. I've updated my answer.

Comment: thank you. So you discard  ```for``` loop; can you clarify where is wrong with ```for``` loop?

Comment: In general, I wouldn't use a for loop if I'm going to modify the loop vble in the loop body. And in this case, using `for i in third_gen:` is like calling `third_gen.send(None)` on every iteration, so your original example was calling `send` twice on every iteration.

Comment: "so your original example was calling send twice on every iteration." Can you elaborate? I still do not see why "33" "333"etc not yielded

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it working as you expect by adding extra yield to `infinite_Third()` but frankly i don't know why it works.

```
def infinite_Third() -> Generator:
    num = 1
    while True:
        if num % 3 ==0:
            i = yield num
            if i is not None:
                num = i
            yield
        num += 1
```

It seems that, every time `send()` is called, an extra `None` value is put to the generator buffer and extra `yield` looks like consuming that.

Comment: I agree with your observation, would love to see some doc that can confirm "every time send() is called, an extra None value is put to the generator buffer"

Comment: `send` isn't sending extra `None`s, and generators do not have a buffer. The `next` calls performed by the `for` loop are sending the extra `None`s.