# Python generator not providing yield when it should

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield

I have a script which has been simplified to provide me with a sequence of numbers.
I have run this under windows 10, using both Python3.6 and Python3.8

If the script is run with the line the line : pal_gen.send(10 ** (digits)) commented out, I get what I expected. But I want to change the sequence when num % 10 = 0.

The script:

```
def infinite_pal():
num = 0
while True:
    #print(f"num= {str(num)}")
    if num % 10 ==0:
        #if num==20: print(f"Have num of {str(num)}")
        i = (yield num)
        #if num==20: print(i)
        if i is not None:
            num = i
            #print(f"i = {str(i)}   num= {str(num)}")
    num += 1
    if num==112: break

pal_gen = infinite_pal()
for i in pal_gen:
    print(i)
    digits = len(str(i))
    #print(f"result = {str(10 ** (digits))}")
    pal_gen.send(10 ** (digits))
```

gives 0,  30

I would have expected: 0, 10, 20, 20, 20 etc.

When num has the value of 20, the yield expression appears to be called, but the value 20 is never sent to the calling for i in pal_gen loop. The num value does get upto 30 and is yielded. 30 should not appear.

Have I totally misunderstood the effect of the .send
Many thanks. I can do this another way but I am puzzled why the above does not work.

From an earlier question, [python generator yield statement not yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327603/python-generator-yield-statement-not-yield), I tried - but it still does not give what I would expect:

```
def infinite_pal():
    num = 0
    while True:
    if num % 10 ==0:
        #if num==20: print(f"Have num of {str(num)}")
        i = (yield num)
        #if num==20: print(i)
        if i is not None:
            num = i
            #print(f"i = {str(i)}   num= {str(num)}")
    num += 1

pal_gen = infinite_pal()
i = pal_gen.send(None)
while True:
    print(i)
    digits = len(str(i))
    #print(f"result = {str(10 ** (digits))}")
    i=pal_gen.send(10 ** (digits))
    if i>200: break
```

Comment: Please post your code with correct indentation. Badly indented Python code is not a [mre] unless you're asking about indentation problems.

Comment: BTW: you run  `send(10)` to send to function but inside function you have `num += 1` so you check `if 11 % 10 == 0` but probably you expect `if 10 % 10 == 0`

Comment: I don't understand why you expect result `0, 10, 20, 20, 20`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you expect result `0, 10, 20, 20, 20` if you send `10`, `100`, `1000`, `10000`

In second version you have to send

```
i = pal_gen.send(10*(digits-1))
```

but it will gives endless `20` so if you expect other values then it will need totally different code.

---

```
def infinite_pal():
    num = 0
    while True:
        if num % 10 ==0:
            i = yield num
            if i is not None:
                num = i
        num += 1

pal_gen = infinite_pal()
i = pal_gen.send(None)
while True:
    print(i)
    digits = len(str(i))
    i = pal_gen.send(10*(digits-1))
    ## `i` never will be bigger then `20` so next lines are useless
    #if i > 200:
    #    break
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did not realise send receives as well as send. Also, if I use next(), it seems to do a send with None. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, `send()` and `next()` run generator and get yielded value

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the above comments. In case anyone else is new to generators in Python, I make the following comments. The first example came from a web site (2 sites in fact) that supposedly explained Python generators. I appreciate there was an error in the .send parameter, but my real concern was why the first approach did not work. I made the comment:

"When num has the value of 20 in the generator, the yield expression appears to be called, but the value 20 is never sent to the calling for i in pal_gen loop", ie print(i) never displayed 20.

I know that the generator yielded 20 because when I uncommented the line in the generator:

```
#if num==20: print(f"Have num of {str(num)}")
```

20 was displayed.

At the time I did not realise that .send also gets the yielded values, so the variable i in print(i) in the for loop only received every second yielded value.

The second example solved this problem although the calculation for .send parameter was incorrect.